# Auth0 is failing localauthsetup 3 times and later i am able to route to the home page

Tags: angular, authentication, auth0

When I login through auth0 - the localauthsetup is failing 3 times and next it is returning true to login, can you please help me with this?

localauthsetup and handleAuthCallback are called in the appcomponent which is similar calling in construction.

Domain id and client id is imported from the config file and it is also working as expected and the code working is almost same as it is there in the link provide:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login#add-the-authentication-service

```js
auth0Client$ = (from(
    createAuth0Client({
      domain: AuthConfig.domain,
      client_id: AuthConfig.clientId,
      redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}`
    })
  ) as Observable<Auth0Client>).pipe(
    shareReplay(1), // Every subscription receives the same shared value
    catchError(err => _throw(err))
  );
  // Define observables for SDK methods that return promises by default
  // For each Auth0 SDK method, first ensure the client instance is ready
  // concatMap: Using the client instance, call SDK method; SDK returns a promise
  // from: Convert that resulting promise into an observable
  isAuthenticated$ = this.auth0Client$.pipe(
    concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.isAuthenticated())),
    tap(res => this.loggedIn = res)
  );
  handleRedirectCallback$ = this.auth0Client$.pipe(
    concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.handleRedirectCallback()))
  );
  // Create subject and public observable of user profile data
  private userProfileSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  userProfile$ = this.userProfileSubject$.asObservable();
  // Create a local property for login status
  loggedIn: boolean = null;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log('service called');
    //calling localauthsetup and handleAuthCallback here 

   }

  // When calling, options can be passed if desired
  // https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#getuser
  getUser$(options?): Observable<any> {
    return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
      concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getUser(options))),
      tap(user => this.userProfileSubject$.next(user))
    );
  }

  localAuthSetup() {
    // This should only be called on app initialization
    // Set up local authentication streams
    const checkAuth$ = this.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
      concatMap((loggedIn: boolean) => {
        console.log('localauthsetup',loggedIn);
        if (loggedIn) {
          // If authenticated, get user and set in app
          // NOTE: you could pass options here if needed
          return this.getUser$();
        }
        // If not authenticated, return stream that emits 'false'
        return of(loggedIn);
      })
    );
    checkAuth$.subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log('subscripbe',res)
    });
  }

  login(redirectPath: string = '/') {
    console.log('login called',redirectPath);
    // A desired redirect path can be passed to login method
    // (e.g., from a route guard)
    // Ensure Auth0 client instance exists
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
      // Call method to log in
      client.loginWithRedirect({
        redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}`,
        appState: { target: redirectPath }
      });
    });
  }

  handleAuthCallback() {
    console.log('handleauth called');
    // Call when app reloads after user logs in with Auth0
    const params = window.location.search;
    if (params.includes('code=') && params.includes('state=')) {
      let targetRoute: string; // Path to redirect to after login processsed
      const authComplete$ = this.handleRedirectCallback$.pipe(
        // Have client, now call method to handle auth callback redirect
        tap(cbRes => {
          // Get and set target redirect route from callback results
          targetRoute = cbRes.appState && cbRes.appState.target ? cbRes.appState.target : '/';
        }),
        concatMap(() => {
          // Redirect callback complete; get user and login status
          return combineLatest([
            this.getUser$(),
            this.isAuthenticated$
          ]);
        })
      );
      // Subscribe to authentication completion observable
      // Response will be an array of user and login status
      authComplete$.subscribe(([user, loggedIn]) => {
        // Redirect to target route after callback processing
        this.router.navigate([targetRoute]);
      });
    }
  }

  logout() {
    // Ensure Auth0 client instance exists
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
      // Call method to log out
      client.logout({
        client_id: AuthConfig.clientId,
        returnTo: `${window.location.origin}`
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's Konrad here. I'm Auth0 Community Engineer. Not an Angular expert but as I can see looking at our quickstart and your code snippet you're not invoking  localAuthSetup methood anywhere you just have it defined as well as handleAuthCallback. Can you try calling both in the constructor as it's suggested in the quickstart?

Comment: Hey Konrad, i tried calling in authservice constructor file - but that is also not working for me. Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: So you basically implemented it EXACTLY as it is shown on the code snippets in the quickstart and it's still not working?

Answer (score 0):

Login to your tenant, go to the spa app, settings.
Find the Allowed Callback URLs and make sure you have something like this there`

your_domain, 
your_domain/login
"""

PS "/login" is the same  path of Application Login URI